# An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request. - configuration program.cs?

Tags: c#, .net, clean-architecture

i have communication problem while retrieving data from the database

ContractDataService

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using ContractShortening.Core.Entities;
using ContractShortening.Core.Interfaces;
using ContractShortening.Infrastructure.Data;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace ContractShortening.Infrastructure.Services;

public class ContractDataService : IContractDataService
{
  private readonly DataDbContext _context;

  //Task<IQueryable<ContractData>> ExecAsync(string ContractNumberPar);
  public async Task<IQueryable<ContractData>> ExecAsync(string contractNumberPar)
  {
    return _context.ContractData
        .FromSqlRaw("[egeria].[ContractData_P] " + contractNumberPar);
  }
}
```

DataDbContext

```
using Ardalis.EFCore.Extensions;
using ContractShortening.Core;
using ContractShortening.SharedKernel;
using MediatR;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using ContractShortening.Core.Entities;

namespace ContractShortening.Infrastructure.Data
{
  public class DataDbContext : DbContext
  {


    public DataDbContext(DbContextOptions<DataDbContext> options) 
      : base(options)
    {

    }

    public DbSet<ContractData> ContractData { get; }


  }
}
```

IContractDataService

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using ContractShortening.Core.Entities;

namespace ContractShortening.Core.Interfaces
{
    public interface IContractDataService
    {
    Task<IQueryable<ContractData>> ExecAsync(string ContractNumberPar);
    }
}
```

DataApiController

```
using DevExtreme.AspNet.Data;
using DevExtreme.AspNet.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using ContractShortening.Core.Interfaces;

namespace ContractShortening.Web.Api
{
    [Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
    public class DataApiController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IContractDataService _data;

        public DataApiController(
        IContractDataService data
          )
        {
            _data = data;
         }




        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetQuery(DataSourceLoadOptions loadOptions, string contractNumberPar)
        {

          var processes = (await _data.ExecAsync("35/0698/19")).Select(i => new
          {
            i.ContractNumber
            ,i.TypeOfLeasing
            ,i.CodeClient
            ,i.Short
            ,i.NameOfClient
            ,i.Amortization
            ,i.Currency
            ,i.ContractValue
            ,i.NumberOfInstallments
            ,i.FinalValue
            ,i.FinalValuePercent
            ,i.TypeOfBaseRate
            ,i.ValueOfBaseRate
            ,i.REFI
            ,i.InstallmentNumber
            ,i.Type
            ,i.MaturityDate
            ,i.NetAmount
            ,i.CapitalRemaining
          });

          return Json(DataSourceLoader.Load(processes, loadOptions));
        }

 
        
        
    }
}
```

Program.cs

```
using Ardalis.ListStartupServices;
using Autofac;
using Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using ContractShortening.Core;
using ContractShortening.Infrastructure;
using ContractShortening.Core.Interfaces;
using ContractShortening.Infrastructure.Data;
using ContractShortening.Infrastructure.Services;
using ContractShortening.Web;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Host.UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory());

builder.Services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
{
    options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
    options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
});

builder.Services.AddScoped<IActiveDirectoryService, ActiveDirectoryService>();


string defaultConnection = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
string seriLogDB = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("SeriLogDB");
string ADConnection = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("ADConnection");

builder.Services.AddDbContext(defaultConnection);
//builder.Services.AddDbContext(seriLogDB);
//builder.Services.AddDbContext(ADConnection);
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ActiveDirectoryDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString(ADConnection)));
builder.Services.AddDbContext<DataDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString(defaultConnection)));
//builder.Services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString(defaultConnection)));

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews().AddNewtonsoftJson();
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();


#region snippet_MigrationsAssembly


builder.Services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(
            builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString(defaultConnection),
            x => x.MigrationsAssembly("ContractShortening.Migration")));


#endregion


builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "My API", Version = "v1" });
    c.EnableAnnotations();
});

// add list services for diagnostic purposes - see https://github.com/ardalis/AspNetCoreStartupServices
builder.Services.Configure<ServiceConfig>(config =>
{
    config.Services = new List<ServiceDescriptor>(builder.Services);

    // optional - default path to view services is /listallservices - recommended to choose your own path
    config.Path = "/listservices";
});


//builder.Host.ConfigureContainer<ContainerBuilder>(containerBuilder =>
//{
//  //containerBuilder.RegisterModule(new DefaultCoreModule());
//  //containerBuilder.RegisterModule(new DefaultInfrastructureModule(builder.Environment.EnvironmentName == "Development"));
//});


builder.Logging.ClearProviders();
builder.Logging.AddConsole();
//builder.Logging.AddAzureWebAppDiagnostics(); add this if deploying to Azure

var app = builder.Build();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    app.UseShowAllServicesMiddleware();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}
app.UseRouting();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseCookiePolicy();

// Enable middleware to serve generated Swagger as a JSON endpoint.
app.UseSwagger();

// Enable middleware to serve swagger-ui (HTML, JS, CSS, etc.), specifying the Swagger JSON endpoint.
app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API V1"));

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
    endpoints.MapRazorPages();
});

// Seed Database
using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
{
    var services = scope.ServiceProvider;

    try
    {
        var context = services.GetRequiredService<AppDbContext>();
                           //context.Database.Migrate();
        context.Database.EnsureCreated();
        SeedData.Initialize(services);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        var logger = services.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();
        logger.LogError(ex, "An error occurred seeding the DB.");
    }
}

app.Run();
```

error

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type
> 'ContractShortening.Core.Interfaces.IContractDataService' while attempting to activate
> 'ContractShortening.Web.Api.DataApiController'.
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider
> sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, bool isDefaultParameterRequired)

> Stack Query Cookies Headers Routing
> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type  > 'ContractShortening.Core.Interfaces.IContractDataService' while attempting to activate  > 'ContractShortening.Web.Api.DataApiController'.
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider  > sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, bool isDefaultParameterRequired)
> lambda_method620(Closure , IServiceProvider , object[] )
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerActivatorProvider+<>c__DisplayClass7_0. > b__0(ControllerContext controllerContext)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerFactoryProvider+<>c__DisplayClass6_0. > g__CreateController|0(ControllerContext controllerContext)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref  > Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker. > g__Awaited|25_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State  > next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSeale > d context)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope  > scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker. > g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker. > g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint  > endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
> Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
> Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext,  > ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
> Ardalis.ListStartupServices.ShowAllServicesMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext  > context)

Show raw exception details

Comment: No idea, but as a side issue: you have a serious SQL injection problem (and possibly syntax error) at `FromSqlRaw("[egeria].[ContractData_P] " + contractNumberPar);` you should use proper parameterization like this `FromSqlRaw("exec [egeria].[ContractData_P] {0}", contractNumberPar);`

Comment: You have forgotten to register your service ```IContractDataService``` in DI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```cs
builder.Services.AddScoped<IContractDataService, ContractDataService>()
// Or depending on your service behavior [..].AddTransient(..) or [..].AddSingleton(..)
```

... to your `Program.cs`

[Documentation about DI can be found here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-6.0)